# Catch EditText events, but prevent it from updating the text (Android)

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to have the following feature: have a text field (i.e., `EditText`) where the user can enter text. I want to catch the event (and know what the user has typed) but I want that text not to be written in the field (or maybe for instance written as A not matter what the user puts in).

How can that be done? I mean, `beforeTextChanged` doesn't allow me to prevent from writing the text.

Comment: why beforeTextChanged doesn't help you?

Comment: How do I prevent the new text from being visible? I thought of maybe overriding the replace function, but not sure if that would help and how to do so (EditText doesn't have a replace function).

Comment: catch the hint - `setText("")`